# Need assistance with basics of developing an interface in WPF

Tags: wpf

I have several questions in regards to creating a WPF interface. I am having a difficult time wrapping my head around how the more advanced XAML techniques can be implemented. I could probably "get by" by using code snippets from the web, but honestly I'd much rather really learn it and then use code snippets for ideas and actually understand what it's doing.

If anyone has any recommendations as to good starter books i'd really appreciate that. Also, I would be very interested in a "tutor" for WPF. I would be interested in detailed explanations of how to do things and I would obviously compensate you for your time (over phone, skype, whatever).

I have read dozens of articles and I purchased WPF 4 unleashed, but I am just having a tough time grasping some of the concepts because I learn much better when I have someone there to answer questions for me.

Thanks for any assistance and I apologize if this is an inappropriate post, but I have used stackoverflow many times as a resource and I know there are some very creative and knowledgeable people in this community.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Pluralsight Trainings](https://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/login/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=/microsoft/assessments)... they cover basic intermediate and advanced WPF to implement WPF apps and also with Silverlight, MVVM and PRISM.